# Laravel query builder finding duplicate data

Tags: laravel, duplicates

I have a table named diplomas which have the following structure:
id, user_id, course_id

I need to find duplicate course_id's for a given user and remove them. Since there was a bug in the diploma issuing logic many duplicates are now present.

Duplicate data example:

```
id  user_id course_id
432    342      44
433    342      44
434    342      44
```

What I have tried:

```
Diploma::select(DB::raw('count(course_id) As occurrences'))->groupBy('course_id')->having('occurrences', >, 1)->get();
```

This doesn't really return what I want since i'm pretty new to query builder I have no idea how to achieve such thing.

Answer (score 0):

I can use the method

```
take()
```

And then the method

```
destroy()
```

For example if you have 3 duplicates you can use

```
take(2)->destroy()
```

if you have the collection grouped.

More info in: 
https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-take

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your query with this

```
Diploma::select(DB::raw('count(`course_id`) as `occurrences`'))
->groupBy('course_id')
->having('occurrences', '>', 1)
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this instead:

```
$results = Diploma::whereIn('id', function ( $query ) {
        $query->select('id')
            ->from('diplomas')
            ->groupBy(['course_id', 'user_id'])
            ->havingRaw('count(*) > 1');
    })->get();
```

Please let me know :)